# Error 107 invalid date with parse REST API

Tags: rest, facebook-graph-api, curl, parse-platform, datetime-format

I'm trying to authenticate a facebook user using parse REST API, but after sending the json via CURL, it gives me the following error message:

```
{  
   "code":107,
   "error":"Invalid date"
}
```

The documentation states the following about the `expiration_date` format in the json that must be sent:

```
{
  "facebook": {
    "id": "user's Facebook id number as a string",
    "access_token": "an authorized Facebook access token for the user",
    "expiration_date": "token expiration date of the format: yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
  }
}
```

Here is the code I'm using for setting the date to the ISO8601 format that I think parse requires:

```
$session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
$token = $session->getToken();
$info = $session->getSessionInfo();
$expiresAt = $info->getExpiresAt();
$expiresAtFormatted = $expiresAt->format(\DateTime::ISO8601);

$facebook = array(
    'authData' => array(
        'facebook' => array(
            'id' => $id,
            'access_token' => $token,
            'expiration_date' => $expiresAtFormatted
        )
    )
);
$facebookJson = json_encode($facebook);
```

And here is the `var_dump` of the `$expiresAtFormatted` variable:

```
string(24) "2015-02-23T18:17:59+0000"
```